# State function of two electrons in 1D box

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, pauli-exclusion-principle

I would like to know how to derive the wave function of two non-intering electrons in one-dimensional space by accounting their spin and Pauli's exclusion principle.

$\Psi(x_1, x_2,\sigma_1, \sigma_2)$  and  $V(x_1, x_2) = V(x_1) + V(x_2)$

I'm just wondering that if I can use the form of separable wavefunction

$\Psi(x_1, x_2,\sigma_1, \sigma_2) = \psi(x_1, x_2) \cdot \chi(\sigma_1, \sigma_2) 
= \psi_1(x_1)\psi_2(x_2) \cdot \chi_1(\sigma_1)\chi_2(\sigma_2)$

Subtituting it in Schrodinger equation would yeild the same result as the case without spin.

Answer (score 2):

You did not yet account for Pauli's exclusion principle.
For this the wave function needs to be [antisymmetric on
exchanging the particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_exclusion_principle#Connection_to_quantum_state_symmetry) $1$ and $2$, i.e.
$$\Psi(x_1,x_2,\sigma_1,\sigma_2)=-\Psi(x_2,x_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_1)$$

You can achieve this with the following wavefunction
$$\begin{align}
\Psi(x_1,x_2,\sigma_1,\sigma_2)
&= \psi_1(x_1)\psi_2(x_2) \cdot \chi_1(\sigma_1)\chi_2(\sigma_2) \\
&- \psi_1(x_2)\psi_2(x_1) \cdot \chi_1(\sigma_2)\chi_2(\sigma_1)
\end{align}$$
which satisfies both Schrödinger's equation and Pauli's exclusion principle.

Comment: Thank you for reply. So, in this case the spin state of each can be different, can’t it?

Comment: @TommyWang Yes, $\chi_1$ and $\chi_2$ may be different,